# cancel / reverse the github commit with netbeans

Tags: netbeans, github

I accidentally did a 'merge origin/master' from netbeans which ended up updating a lot of files in github.

How do I back out of that commit from netbeans?

Answer (score 1):

Reset is one solution:

- if you haven't push already
- if if you are the only one working on that repo (in which case, even if you already pushed the commit, you will be able to push --force)
- if that merge was the only modification you did

Then:

- Team -> Git -> Reset... (NetBeans 7.3.x), or
- Team -> Git-> Revert/Recover-> Reset... (or contextual menu) (NetBeans 7.4+)

You can do a hard reset to the previous commit (if you committed your merge).
Or you can do a hard reset to the current HEAD (if you didn't tet committed your merge)